# getElementById for specific html tag

Tags: javascript

In fact, I am working on a small PHP script.On a page the PHP generates code like this :

```
<div id="ya">sjaka</div>
<p id="ya"><input id="color" type="text" value="text1"></input></p>
<span id="ya"><input id="color" type="text" value="text2"></input></span>
```

What i want is that to get the value of the input inside the span with the id ya.for that reason i am using this js code :

```
x = document.getElementById("ya");
 color = x.querySelector("#color").value;
```

But it doesn't seem to work it returns the result inside the P tag.How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can't have elements with same `id`

Comment: Or rather, you *shouldn't* have elements with the same `id`. Use the `class` property instead, and keep the `id`s unique.

Comment: @Belatar -- please do not edit your question off the answers. If you have a question ask a new one, or see the answers to the duplicate

Answer (score 6):

You **should not** have multiple elements on the page with the same ID.

ids should be unique.

Consider using a class instead.

Otherwise JavaScript just chooses one of them to select.

Comment: You are right :) thanks what if the ids are now classes ? how to choose the span class only ?

Comment: span isnt a class. Please see answers to the duplicate